# Android : Post Request using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android

How to make POST request using `HttpUrlConnection` ?

I have tried using `HttpClient` but it is now deprecated

Comment: google + your question + I feel lucky.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage("Logging In ...");
        pdLoading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Constants.SERVER_URL);

            HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("method", "login");
            parameters.put("email", "customer@gmail.com");
            parameters.put("password", "customer123");
            parameters.put("device_token", "123456");
            parameters.put("device_type", "android");
            parameters.put("timezone", "Asia/Kolkata");

            Set set = parameters.entrySet();
            Iterator i = set.iterator();
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : parameters.entrySet()) {
                if (postData.length() != 0) {
                    postData.append('&');
                }

                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                postData.append('=');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
            }

            byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            Log.e(TAG, builder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pdLoading.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: means this is answer to posted Question ?